# How to implement ADFS authentication on MVC.NET Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, adfs

I'm trying to implement ADFS Login on a MVC application.
The ADFS service is from a third party company and the only thing I got from them is the Metadata URL. I've tried a lot of examples from internet, but any of them is working.

Can someone please tell me how I should do this, if I need something more  besides the metadata link(?) or give me the link to a good tutorial to implement ADFS login.

I don't know a lot about ADFS services or authentication and this is my very first time asking something here.

Comment: They keyword you need is **SAML**. You need to implement a SAML Assertion Consumer Service.

Comment: I'm going to try it. I will let you know if it works or not, thank you.

Comment: I'm having a lot of troubles finding documentation about this. It seems like SAML is no longer avaliable to be used from the client side and I have no access to the ADFS server to know how it is configured or if my application is configured as a trusted app. I'm supposed to use OWIN in order to connecto with the ADFS server and complete the login process, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ADFS, the client side must implement WS-Federation, SAML 2.0 or OpenID Connect.

OIDC is ADFS 4.0 only.

There is a NuGet OWIN WS-Fed package as well as one for OIDC.

The easiest way to do this in VS for a new MVC project is "Change Authentication" / "Work or School" / select "On-Premises" from the drop down.

Then enter the parameters from the metadata.

They will have to add your application to ADFS as a Relying Party.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. That's exactly what I'm doing. I used the wizard to create a new project, changing the authentication to "Work or School" and selecting "On-Premises" option. In fact, the metadata URL is the only thing I have, I don't know what I need to enter in the "App ID URI" field and I think the problem is that my ADFS provider doesn't have that "App ID URI" configured in the ADFS Server. I'm going to contact them to ask for help. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: OK - then this will help - http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/